# Implicit conversion not working in different project

Tags: c#, .net, types, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I'm moving some classes around my solution, reorganizing the whole application. In one of my movementes, however, I encountered the following problem:

I have the following line in, let's say, `class A` of `project A`.

```
//manager.GetVote() returns 'XmlBlock', a custom class of ours in another project.
XmlDocument xml = manager.GetVote();
```

Apparently, there is an implicit conversion going on here. Good for me, as long as it works.

When I try to move this class to `project B`, I get the following error in that specific line:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `ProjectC.BloqueXML` to `System.Xml.XmlDocument`

The line looks exactly the same, and the references are right.

What is probably going on here? The implicit conversion is not being made and I don't know where to look to solve this problem.

Comment: Please show the declaration for the implicit conversion. Ideally, show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem....

Comment: Did the old code have another class called `XmlDocument`?